# Redirecting codehaus.org to Internet Archive's Wayback Machine automagically?

Tags: feature-request, external-links, broken-link

http://www.codehaus.org/ terminated their services as of June 1.

http://www.mojohaus.org/ is going to migrate the content but many links to Documentation and Usage pages, FAQs, etc. (in fact all of those I followed during the past few days) lead into the void. This is not too convenient.

Is it feasible to redirect all codehaus.org pages to the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine automagically in the meantime?

Example:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/ redirects to https://web.archive.org/web/*/mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/.

I know that SE answers are supposed to be self-contained. However, more often than not I experience that this rule isn't applied by everyone.

Comment: Any idea on roughly how many that would be ? Looking at this search query: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=URL%3acodehaus.org, quite a lot them have already been edited. Also, it might be better, although a lot of work, to actually edit them to point to where those repositories are now, (github,etc.) To avoid relying on the Internet Archive.

Comment: It's not about code repositories. It's about project/documentation sites. The aforementioned versions-maven-plugin, for instance, has [a github site](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin), but there's not a single word of documentation there. But, while writing this comment I found out that there's a site http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/ with the proper content already. Apparently the redirect from `mojo.codehaus.org/something` to `www.mojohaus.org/something` doesn't work properly on their side. I think this feature request can be closed with that.

Comment: There's a change proposal already: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mojohaus-dev/3uY_fuZxz00

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's a proposal for a solution outside SE.